# Taylor series expansion?

Tags: taylor-expansion

How to find the Taylor series expansion of

$$(1+x)^{1/x}$$

I tried with the Taylor series but unable to solve it. Help me out. Hints or anything that sort will be helpful.

Comment: Differential equations tag?

Comment: Taylor expansion at which point? It has no Taylor expansion at $0$ because the function is not analytic at $0$. At all other points just use Taylor's formula.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko It does have a Taylor expansion at $0$ (to any fixed order), though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\exp(\ln(1+x)/x)=\exp(1-\frac x2+\frac{x^2}3-\frac{x^3}4+...\\
=\exp(1)\exp(-x/2)\exp(x^2/3)\exp(-x^3/4)...\\
=e(1-\frac x2+\frac {x^2}8-...)(1+\frac{x^2}3+\frac{x^4}{18}...)(1-\frac{x^3}4+...)...$$
How many terms do you want?

Comment: I don't understand the last step @Michael

Comment: @KprimeX Composing the expansions: If $f(x) = 1+ax+bx^2 +o(x^2)$ at $0$ and $g(1+y) = cy+ dy^2$ at $0$, then $g(f(x)) = g(1+ax+bx^2 +o(x^2)) = c(ax+bx^2 +o(x^2)) + d(ax+bx^2 +o(x^2))^2 + o(x^2) = \cdots$

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x) = (1+x) ^{\frac1x} \implies \ln f = \frac{\ln(1+x)}x \implies \frac {f'(x)}{f(x)} = \frac1{x^2} (\frac x{1+x} - \ln(1+x))$$

define $g_1(x) = \frac1{x^2} (\frac x{1+x} - \ln(1+x))$.

We have $$f'(x) = g_1(x) f(x) \implies f''(x) = f(x)g_1'(x) + g_1(x) f'(x) = f(x)(g_1'(x) + g_1^2(x))$$

we have a sequence of functions $g_n$ such that $f^{n}(x) = g_n(x) f(x)$ and

$$g_{n+1}(x) = g_n'(x) + g_n(x)^2$$

we also know that $f(0) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) = e$ and $g_{n}(0) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} g_n(x)$. With the help of a Python program, I got first terms:

$$(1+x)^{\frac1x} = e(1-\frac x2 + \frac{11x^2}{24}-\frac{7x^3}{8} + \frac{2447x^4}{5760} -... )$$